# Terraform - Is the unique id in .tfstate file always never used before?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-gcp

In the Terraform State File, following is a section of .tfstate file against OpenStack (which uses AWS APIs and hence AWS is the provider) :

```
"aws_instance.7.3" 
  "primary": {
    "attributes": { 
      "id": "6b646e50-..."
```

Say I delete an instance/resource manually in the console.
My Terraform Configuration can be changed in such a way that Terraform Plan can either trigger a 
i) re-create (+/-) or a 
ii) destroy (-) and a create/add (+).

**Question is** : In either case, is there a possibility for the new node that is created to have the same "id" attribute as it had before in the state file ?

In other words, will `"id"` attribute (`"instance_id"` in case of GCP) be always unique throughout the infrastructure's lifecycle?
(so that I know a new node is created/re-created for sure when comparing the old tfstate file with new tfstate file against `"id"` or `"instance_id"` attribute and ensure .tfstate reflects what was said to happen in the plan.)

The reason I am checking if the .tfstate reflects the plan (exact number of creates/re-creates/destroy) is, though the "apply" happens according to the "plan", sometimes the .tfstate DOES NOT reflect that.

> The reason for this is that after "apply" , terraform seems to do a
>   GET call to the provider to update the .tfstate file and this GET call
>   sometimes returns inconsistent state of the infrastucture (i.e it may
>   not return a node's details even though it is created and is part of the
>   infrastructure !).

In that case I have to let know in our automated tool that .tfstate did not happen according to the plan and so there is a possible corruption/inconsistency in the .tfstate file to fix it with manual import.